# PHP/.htaccess: removing php extension from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was using .htaccess code to remove .php extension for all my web pages. Here's the code I use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond /%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/$ /$1.php
```

It doesn't seem to work. I think I'm missing something. When I type www.mysite.com/about/ to get www.mysite.com/about.php it returns error 404 (page not found). Can someone please shed some light.

Thanks,
Paul G.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If folder does not exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# and file exist
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
# uncomment the below rule if you want the "/" to be required 
# otherwise leave as is
# RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [L]
# internally show the content of filename.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

The above rule will:

1. will not redirect if a folder exist
2. will not redirect if the file does not exist
3. will redirect what comes before the `/` if one is present as the file name

So it will work for all these examples:

```
http://domain.com/about/
http://domain.com/about
http://domain.com/contact/
http://domain.com/contact
```

If you want you can remove the `?`, like the commented rule, to make it accept only URL's that end with a `/`.

```
http://domain.com/about/
http://domain.com/contact/
```

Now these are important step for the above to work:

1. It must go into the `.htaccess` on your root folder for example `/home/youraccount/public_html/.htaccess`
2. The Options before the rewrite rule are very important specially `-MultiViews`
3. The file must exist on the same place the `.htaccess` is for example in your case the `about.php` file
4. The PHP must be working obviously.

Comment: It works without the trailing slash "/", once I add slash, it loads the page without styling, and when navigate to another page it returns 404 error, and the url tunrs to www.mysite.com/about/services.

Comment: @netizen0911 that's because youre using relative paths for css, images and javascript, instead of using `css/my.css` you need to use the full URL like this `http://domain.com/css/my.css` on your HTML. When using relative URL like `css/my.css` it will assume that the file is on the same folder in your case it would assume `http://domain.com/about/css/my.css` and that's why it fails.

Comment: Yup, I figured that one out, but how about getting 404 error when navigating from the address where there's a trailing slash "/" at the end? (i.e. when I have www.mysite.com/about/ up and click on contact.php link, it gives www.mysite.com/about/contact/ instead of www.mysite.com/contact/)

Comment: @netizen0911 same reason you're using relative path for your URL's you need to use full path. `<a href="/contact/">contact</a>` will give you one result while `<a href="contact/">contact</a>` will give a different one from `<a href="http://domain.com/contact/">contact</a>`, same goes for images, CSS, JavaScript and any other resources.

Comment: I changed all relative links to absolute, but when I type the address with trailing slash "/" it still shows the page with no styles unlike typing in without "/" which loads just fine. I have it hosted on Godaddy, if that makes any difference. Any idea?

Comment: @netizen0911 without seeing the page I won't be able to tell what is wrong as it is not related to htaccess but HTML

Comment: I think I have figured it out. It must be with the web cache, because when I checked the source of non-styled page the stylesheet links was still relative. It's interesting why it took more or less an hour for the server to update it. Can I use the same snippet for sub-folder pages?

Comment: Its good to have 1 browser you never use around for this things, if browser A is cached you check with browser B to make sure, as for multi-level folders, the rule would be different, `RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]` just replace the above `RewriteRule` with this one and keep the 2 `RewriteCond`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the slash at the end of your rule might be there, or it might not. Adding a `?` makes it optional, so that `mysite.com/about` and `mysite.com/about/` will both match.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/?$ /$1.php
```

It's hard to say if this is what's causing your problem, or if something else is, though. Does `mysite.com/about.php` also give you an error?