# URL Masking - making filenames into folders?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-masking

I'm not very technical with any code other than HTML so bear with me! This has me stumped so I'd really appreciate help with this.

I've got a simple site with file names like `index.php`, `portfolio.php`, `portfolio-001.php`, `about.php` etc. When people are browsing my site, they see:

- `"mysite.com/index.php"`
- `"mysite.com/portfolio.php"`
- `"mysite.com/portfolio-001.php"`
- `"mysite.com/about.php"`

in the browser's address bar.

My question is, how can I rewrite/mask the URL so that while they are visiting the pages, they will see:

- `"mysite.com/"`
- `"mysite.com/portfolio/"`
- `"mysite.com/portfolio/001"`
- `"mysite.com/about/"`

respectively?

Thanks, really appreciate the help!

Alex

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP/.htaccess: removing php extension from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751890/php-htaccess-removing-php-extension-from-url)

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?.

Comment: Yes, I've tried using this article:https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

But it doesn't work

Comment: I saw that link squeamish, but I couldn't figure it out - it shows how to remove the .php, but I need to sometimes create two folders (portfolio/001) instead of just removing the extension