# htaccess Rewrite directory to php pages

Tags: php, .htaccess

Say I have these pages stored in the root:

```
page1.php
page2.php
```

how do I rewrite this:

```
domain.com/page1/
```

to:

```
domain.com/page1.php
```

P.S.Also need to make sure the rewritten url does not clash with a real directory.

**UPDATE:**
Solutions below were only working on my remote server, but not localhost Xampp server.
I added this first line to my htaccess and solutions below worked on my local server!

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP/.htaccess: removing php extension from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751890/php-htaccess-removing-php-extension-from-url)

Answer (score 1):

You may use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Rule in `/root/.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine On

#skip real files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# rewrite /file/ to /file.php if /file/ exists as .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to redirect a small number of pages, you could do this:

```
RewriteRule    ^page1/?$    /page1.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^page2/?$    /page2.php    [NC,L]
```

You might want to consider something like the following, though, where you pass the number as an argument (assuming you are following a naming convention as you described).

```
^page/([0-9]+)/?$   /pageLoader.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
```